# Why am I getting "Abstract Error" when working with TStream class?

Tags: delphi

When I try to run the following simple code sequence, I'm getting the `Abstract Error` error message:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ImageStream: TStream;
begin
  ImageStream := TStream.Create;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ImageStream);
  ...
end;
```

I need to extract the stream of an `TBitmap` for later processing... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You could have avoided this be heeding the compiler warning about instantiating an abstract class. Never ignore a compiler warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [TStream class](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TStream) is an abstract class, and the foundation of all the streams.

> TStream is the **base class** type for stream objects that can read from or write to various kinds of storage media, such as disk files, dynamic memory, and so on.
>
> Use specialized stream objects to read from, write to, or copy information stored in a particular medium.

You may want to use the [TMemoryStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TMemoryStream) or [TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TFileStream), which, as the name implies, store the stream content in memory or a system file.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ImageStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ImageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ImageStream);
    ...
  finally
    ImageStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: forgot , same like tstrings and TStringlist :-(